# How do I get my HTML files online?

Tags: web

I've built a couple of web pages in HTML. How do I go about getting them on the internet so that I can type in my website name and see the files. I've bought the "domain name" I want from godaddy but I don't understand how to put my files on it. Thanks, Rob.

Comment: You'll need a place to actually put those files. A hosting service. Did your GoDaddy purchase include any space or was it the name only?

Comment: GoDaddy provides hosting services. You might want to go to their site and read up on it. They have various links.

Comment: This Question Should be on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) Really.

Google for Web Hosting you'll get an overview about Hosting services and choose the one appropriate for you.

For free hosting i'll suggest : [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I will check out your hosting options also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get hosting set up. Buying the domain name is the first part, but you now have to buy hosting so that your files have a place to live. After you have hosting (which is just a computer/server somewhere that you put files on) you have to point your domain name to your webhost by setting the nameservers at GoDaddy to the ones your new webhost gives you. There's a lot more info on this stuff at [Syntaxxx.com](http://www.syntaxxx.com). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Upload them via ftp to your domain's/account's root directory or just use the built-in Godaddy file uploader if you have some hosting plan with Godaddy. If you don't, sign up for a free web hosting service and make sure your Godaddy domain forwards to that free hosting service's address for your site. Godaddy can do the forwarding in such a way that when you go to www.yourdomain.com, even if it's forwarding to www.00freehosting.com/something/you, it can still just say www.yourdomain.com. Also, make sure you have an index.html or index.php, which is the default file that will be looked for when you navigate to a page.